# Is that possible to make dynamic importing failed manually?

Tags: javascript

I want to make [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) must fail manually.

pseudo-code:

```js
// Do some magic for import(), make the promise rejected manually.
// Set some magic prop to make the next dynamic import must fail.
// import.__rejected = true

function main() {
  return import('./mod')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Assuming that the `./mod` module always exists. Is this possible?

Comment: Whats happens if you change the name of the import path?

Comment: @LeandroMatilla This is a restriction. I can't change the import path. I know if the imported module does not exist, the dynamic import promise will reject. As far as I know, only this situation will make the promise of dynamic import rejected. But I am looking for another manual way.

Comment: So in your `./mod` file create an exception like `return throw true; `

Comment: @LeandroMatilla Thanks. Can I control it on the side of dependency? I mean in the `main.js` file. Besides, Besides, `return` keyword should be used in a functional scope, not module scope. So, your code snippet is incorrect.

Comment: Your `mod` must be inside a big try catch

Comment: @LeandroMatilla Yea, I can throw an error in the module scope. But the key is how to control it when calling the `import()` function.

Comment: Check this post => https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader/issues/280